# How to add tooltips using Visual Studio resource editor?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, dialog

I am making a few quick small applications and using the Visual Studio Dialog editor to speed things up and keep it simple.  I cannot see a way to add tooltips to the controls from the visual editor. Is it easily possible?
Thanks
Allan

Comment: Tooltips are separate controls that can only be created programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following on MSDN which allows you to easily add tooltips to resources using a single line.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298368(v=vs.85).aspx

I have the following line on my WM_INITDIALOG to add a tooltip to a checkbox control:

CreateToolTip(IDC_CHECK_GAMEMODE, hDlgWnd, TEXT("I'm a helper!"));

This is the easiest way I have found to add tooltips to dialogs created in the visual editor.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no tooltip control in the visual editor, maybe you should add it from a code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.textBox1, "Hello");
```

Comment: How do you know which language the OP is using? :)

Comment: I am using plain old win32 wrapped in my own c++ classes with no MFC. I know how to create windows with tooltips from code, but it seems a little strange that the visual editor cannot add tooltips for you.

Is there a way to add the tootips class to controls made from the visuael editor?

Comment: @allan: The resource editor is a graphical frontend to the [Resource File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007.aspx). Since the resource file format has no way to specify a tooltip for a control, neither can the resource editor.